# How can I control access to a Wifi Router using Python-Flask?

Tags: python, wifi, router

I would like to write a mini web-app to control clients' internet access on a Wifi-router.

How can I block/regulate their Internet usage while connected to the router?

Each client would have a login username & password. I do not want to use a *MAC-address filter* as they could login using any device.

Comment: Wireless, wired, or both?

Comment: @payne Wireless for a start. I guess I'll be able to figure out 'wired' once I'm done with 'wireless'.

Answer (score 0):

For wireless access control, look at a [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) server.  From Wikipedia:

> Remote Authentication Dial In User Service (RADIUS) is a networking
>   protocol that provides centralized Authentication, Authorization, and
>   Accounting (AAA) management for users who connect and use a network
>   service.

A free RADIUS server:  http://freeradius.org/

It's supported by some of the better consumer access points, such as the ASUS RT-N66U.